# Add binary script to "Approved apps" list for MacOS Notifications and Focus

Tags: macos, notifications

I want to add a binary to the Approved apps list in the MacOS Notifications & Focus settings but it doesn't show up as an option like a normal app.

I've added the binary to `/Applications` to see if the list pulls from a specific directory but the binary script still didn't show up.

Comment: What is a binary script?

Comment: I mean just a binary, will edit

Comment: I should have been more clear: Is this a .app application built with Xcode or a pure unix-style binary?

Comment: Pure unix-style binary.